# Como pegar a data e hora atual sem usar o relógio do computador?

Tags: php, data

Estou com problema no `date`, ele pega a hora do meu relógio do computador e eu queria que pegasse realmente o horário certo.

O resultado do seguinte código é que o `date` pegará do seu servidor do host.

```php
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i');
echo $date;
?>
```

Comment: Certo em qual sentido? como php vc consegue a data/hora do servidor por exemplo(GMT +07:00) com js a do computador local (GMT -03:00).

Comment: AAAAA,o date pega do servido certo?,então tudo bem desculpe essa pergunta

Comment: Talvez ajude: [Obter a data e hora atual pela internet, em aplicação desktop](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13332/2998)

Answer (score 10):

Você pode pegar a data e hora de um servidor [NTP](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol).
Segue um exemplo de código PHP que faz isso:

```
<?php
$socket = fsockopen('udp://pool.ntp.br', 123, $err_no, $err_str, 1);
if ($socket)
{
    if (fwrite($socket, chr(bindec('00'.sprintf('%03d', decbin(3)).'011')).str_repeat(chr(0x0), 39).pack('N', time()).pack("N", 0)))
    {
        stream_set_timeout($socket, 1);
        $unpack0 = unpack("N12", fread($socket, 48));
        echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $unpack0[7]);
    }

    fclose($socket);
}
```

O código completo e com mais precisão você pode encontrar aqui: http://xlo.co/blog/general/php-ntp-client

Answer (score 5):

O PHP pega o horário do servidor em que o apache está rodando. Provavelmente está igual ao relogio do seu computador por estar rodando em um servidor local, porém quando o mesmo script for executado em um servidor hospedado, ele retornará o horário deste servidor.

Comment: obrigado agora eu entendo o problema.

Answer (score 2):

Coloque isso no início do documento:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
```

Aqui funcionou, mas apenas no início do documento.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode definir a data e hora utilizando funções como [`date_date_set`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date-date-set.php).

Porém, você precisará de uma fonte para essa informação. Se você tiver algum servidor por aí, tipo o que hospeda seu site pessoal, pode fazer um script lá em [php](/questions/tagged/php) para pegar a data/hora de lá. Nesse caso, o script local teria que fazer uma requisição ***cross domain*** - entre domínios, ou seja, entre servidores. Tipo: tem horas aí? Mas confesso que nunca fiz isso, prefiro arrumar o relógio do meu PC, de qualquer forma, segue o link se você se interessar: [Client URL](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php).

Answer (score 1):

Pode-se Utilizar desta Forma, o Banco de dados não altera e a vantagem é que não necessita da conversão de date en-US para date pt-BR, ele já é automático

```
<?php
$matricula = date ("Y-m-d");
echo"<input type='date' value='$matricula' name='date'
";
?>
```