# Obter a data e hora atual pela internet, em aplicação desktop

Tags: c#, datetime, delphi-7, aplicação-desktop, ntp

Estou implementando um bloqueio de sistema por data, e preciso obter a data atual de brasília por exemplo, que seria a hora oficial do Brasil, ou a data no time zone -3.

Acredito que haja web services que façam isso e que sejam confiáveis, ou talvez até mesmo o governo disponibilize esse tipo de serviço.

Mas não encontrei nada que me atendesse de forma eficaz. Então estou recorrendo a vocês.

> Obs: Se trata de uma aplicação Desktop e não posso confiar na data da maquina em execução ou do servidor de banco de dados.

Comment: O governo americano mantém o NIST - National Institute of Standards and Technology. Ele dispõe de vários servidores que informam, dentre outras coisas, a hora atual, UTC. Daí é só aplicar o fuso de brasília ou o que você quiser. [Eis a relação de servidores](http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi). Se alguém quiser elaborar sobre isso em uma resposta, fiquem a vontade.

Comment: @bigown e Bacco, não citei na perguntou pois será necessário implementar isto em 2 linguagens, Delphi 7 e C#.

Comment: Metade da pergunta foi respondida, faltou a parte da data.
Como pega a Data no delphi?

Comment: @Márcio você chegou a testar as respostas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Delphi

No Delphi caso você tenha instalado os componentes do `Indy`(*em versões recentes do Delphi o Indy já vem embutido*), você pode obter o horário utilizando o componente `IdSntp`.

Exemplo:

```
{
   Na seção "Uses" coloque as units:
    IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdSNTP,
    IdBaseComponent, IdUDPClient, IdUDPBase
}
Function ReturnTimeInternet(const Servidor: string): string;
Var
SNTP: TIdSNTP;
begin
SNTP := TIdSNTP.Create(nil);
try
 SNTP.Host := Servidor;
 Result := TimeToStr(SNTP.DateTime);
finally
 SNTP.Disconnect;
 SNTP.Free;
end;
end;
```

Exemplo de utilização:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
Tempstr: string;
begin
Tempstr := ReturnTimeInternet('pool.ntp.br'); // Ou um servidor de sua preferência
showmessage(format('O horário atual é %s.',[tempstr]));
end;
```

Answer (score 12):

### Solução em C#

Original: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12150289/916193

```
public static DateTime GetNetworkTime()
{
    //Servidor nacional para melhor latência
    const string ntpServer = "a.ntp.br";

    // Tamanho da mensagem NTP - 16 bytes (RFC 2030)
    var ntpData = new byte[48];

    //Indicador de Leap (ver RFC), Versão e Modo
    ntpData[0] = 0x1B; //LI = 0 (sem warnings), VN = 3 (IPv4 apenas), Mode = 3 (modo cliente)

    var addresses = Dns.GetHostEntry(ntpServer).AddressList;

    //123 é a porta padrão do NTP
    var ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(addresses[0], 123);
    //NTP usa UDP
    var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

    socket.Connect(ipEndPoint);

    //Caso NTP esteja bloqueado, ao menos nao trava o app
    socket.ReceiveTimeout = 3000;     

    socket.Send(ntpData);
    socket.Receive(ntpData);
    socket.Close();

    //Offset para chegar no campo "Transmit Timestamp" (que é
    //o do momento da saída do servidor, em formato 64-bit timestamp
    const byte serverReplyTime = 40;

    //Pegando os segundos
    ulong intPart = BitConverter.ToUInt32(ntpData, serverReplyTime);

    //e a fração de segundos
    ulong fractPart = BitConverter.ToUInt32(ntpData, serverReplyTime + 4);

    //Passando de big-endian pra little-endian
    intPart = SwapEndianness(intPart);
    fractPart = SwapEndianness(fractPart);

    var milliseconds = (intPart * 1000) + ((fractPart * 1000) / 0x100000000L);

    //Tempo em **UTC**
    var networkDateTime = (new DateTime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).AddMilliseconds((long)milliseconds);

    return networkDateTime.ToLocalTime();
}

// stackoverflow.com/a/3294698/162671
static uint SwapEndianness(ulong x)
{
    return (uint) (((x & 0x000000ff) << 24) +
                   ((x & 0x0000ff00) << 8) +
                   ((x & 0x00ff0000) >> 8) +
                   ((x & 0xff000000) >> 24));
}
```