# Obter data e hora independente da hora do sistema

Tags: javascript, time

Bom, estou tendo dificuldades em obter a data e hora em JavaScript quando o computador, ou o sistema estão com esses dados incorretos.

- Hora oficial: 08:35 - 14/07/2016 - Horário de Brasilia
- Hora do computador: 23:46 - 12/07/2016

Não importa o método que eu tente em JavaScript, o horário sempre vem com base na `Hora do computador`, inclusive se tentar `getUTCDate()`, `getTimezoneOffset()`, etc...

Existe algum modo de corrigir esse problema só com JavaScript? Ou preciso mesmo me basear em um horário obtido diretamente em meu servidor?

> Nota: É importante que o horário esteja correto pois é ele que controla o funcionamento de e-commerce do site.

Comment: Já usaste `date.toISOString();`?

Comment: @Sergio sim, com base na `Hora do computador` da questão, esse é o resultado obtido: `2016-07-13T02:51:41.447Z` Ele faz tudo com base na data/hora do sistema

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Não existe forma alguma de fazer isso.

O problema não é de formato ou de fuso horário, é erro do uso hardware que fornece o horário. O JavaScript só pega o que o navegador fornece. O navegador só pega o que o sistema operacional fornece. O SO só fornece o que o hardware fornece. Só o usuário pode mudar o horário já que não existe API no JavaScript para mudar o horário do computador.

A solução é pedir o horário para o servidor, pelo menos a primeira vez para saber o horário correto que você tem controle. Se precisar ir mantendo o horário atualizado pode-se usar uma fórmula para pegar o deslocamento do horário do computador em relação ao horário certo, aí vai pegando o horário do computador e aplicando esse deslocamento antes de mostrar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Não seria possível talvez, e de forma alternativa, pegar o horário oficial de algum webservice publicamente acessível?

Comment: @LuizVieira Sim, mas cai na questão de pegar o horário do servidor, não necessariamente seu. É mais fácil e mais garantido (não depende de uma tecnologia mais nova que pode não estar disponível) pegar do seu.

Comment: Seria isto? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9244/15726

Comment: @GustavoTinoco não porque isto é PHP :P Mas é basicamente isto portado para JS com [Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API).

Comment: Este é para JS na própria pergunta o cara achou as respostas. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900907/good-precision-for-sync-time-with-ntp-over-javascript

Comment: Ou você pega aqui http://www.timeapi.org/  ai você converte a hora UTC para o fuso de Brasília.. etc...

Comment: Esta última eu não sei não, mas na pergunta do SO tem algumas soluções interessantes, ainda que não sei o quanto são confiáveis.

Comment: @GustavoTinoco De qq forma o JS tá pegando de uma fonte externa, e aí já são dados quaisquer (o fato de ser tempo é um detalhe). É uma solução pra ter a informação, mas não é um recurso que o JS tem (cai no que o Bigown falou, o JS nao faz isso, teria que pegar de um servidor, e eu concordo que se é pra pegar, melhor do seu mesmo). Inclusive essa API aí precisa usar JSONP, justamente pra contornar o CORS, que não permite um Ajax normal pegar dados de outro domínio..

Comment: Apesar das soluções serem boas, se não há como fazer isso pleo próprio JS, é mais viável, seguro e garantido fazer (mais) um simples $http e obter o horário atual pelo meu próprio servidor, que por padrão já usa o fuso de Brasília.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade concordo.

Answer (score 2):

Tentei montar um exemplo utilizando as ideias sugeridas pelo **@Maniero**, **@LuizVieira** e **@GustavoTinoco**

```js
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now.json?callback=setDtServer";

var dtServer = null;
var dtClient = null;

//se preferir pode informar um local especifico: ["pt-BR"]
//ou uma lista de locais esperados: ["pt-BR", "pt-PT", "en-US"]
//caso informe uma lista vazia, ele vai tentar inferir o local pelo sistema.
var locales = [];
var formater = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locales , {
  //é possivel informar o time-zone usando uma string no formato IANA
  //você pode encontrar a lista completa em:
  // http://www.iana.org/time-zones
  // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones
  //No exemplo abaixo estou usando o Timezone de Fortaleza, que difere um
  //pouco do de Brasília, por não fazer parte do Horário de Verão.
  //novamente o valor default vai refletir o que for informado pelo sistema.
  timeZone: "America/Fortaleza",

  year: "numeric",
  month: "numeric",
  day: "numeric",
  hour: "numeric",
  minute: "numeric",
  second: "numeric",
  timeZoneName: "long"
});

function getData() {
  var diff = dtServer.getTime() - dtClient.getTime();
  var data = new Date();
  data.setTime(data.getTime() + diff);
  return data;
}

function setDtServer(json) {
  dtServer = new Date(json.dateString);  
  dtClient = new Date();
  document.head.removeChild(script);  
}

document.head.appendChild(script);
window.setInterval(function () {
  var data = getData();
  console.log(formater.format(data));
}, 1234);
```

Para mais informações sobre Internacionalização de Datas com JavaScript:
[`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat)

Se precisar de um Polyfill para o Intl:
[`Intl.js`](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js)
[`intl-locales-supported`](https://github.com/yahoo/intl-locales-supported)

Comment: Neste caso, como determinar qual o timezone? Pois notei que ao buscar rodar o script ele exibe 2 horários: `14/07/2016 10:37:24 BRT` e `09:49:22.447` ainda há uma pequena diferença entre os horários, inclusive os minutos. Obs.: Agora estou com meu relógio do computador no horário oficial de Brasilia

Comment: @CelsomTrindade, fiz uma edição no exemplo e adicionei alguns comentários, talvez ajude a sanar a sua duvida.

Comment: quanto a diferença de minutos, aqui não está acontecendo, tente comparar com algum serviço online, como: http://time.is

Answer (score -4):

```
const options = {
    timeZone: 'America/Sao_Paulo',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric'
};
const date = new Intl.DateTimeFormat([], options);
console.log(date.format(new Date()));
```